# Create ASP.NET page with CodeBehind Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, code-behind

I'd like to create a simple

default.aspx
default.aspx.cs

page dyamically and store it on the server.

I've used StreamWriter to create the directory and both files

The default.aspx I create doesn't access the codebehind.

```
private string displayPage = @"<%@ Page Language=""C#"" AutoEventWireup=""true"" CodeBehind=""Default.aspx.cs""  %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">

<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
<head runat=""server"">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id=""form1"" runat=""server"">
    <div>
        <asp:Label id=""_lblBody"" runat=""server"" />
        <asp:Label id=""_lblFooter"" runat=""server"" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>";

        private string codeBehindPage = @"using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _lblBody.Text = ""Hello World!"";
        }
    }
";
```

Can this be done? Any advice, thanks!

Comment: I think you're going the long way around to be honest. Why not create the html file for the page directly?

Comment: I have to do more advanced things like pulling data from files on the server, etc which an HTML file just isn't practical to do.

Comment: But asp.net only generates html anyway? Otherwise how are you going to compile the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why create a code-behind at all when you can just add that code in the aspx-file? Much simpler and you still have all your page_load events and such

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks and anyone else in the same situation I recommend doing the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use masterpage's codebehind, to hadndle events, and dynamically create only content-pages.

Comment: That's fine but only if I can make the masterpage dynamically as well. I think there is an underlying problem with the way I am trying to dynamically create these pages. I'm hoping someone can recognize that and fix it.